# Switching Phd topic (and advisor)

Tags: phd, graduate-school, advisor

I am a PhD student in computer science. My current advisor was also my masters advisor, and I stayed with him for a PhD because back at the time the research I did under him was interesting for me.
Two years into the PhD, after talking with friends from grad school and exploring different fields in CS, I found myself increasingly drawn into a different topic. I waited for a while, just to make sure this is not a "whim", but a real change in my interests.
At this point I am absolutely sure that new field is what I want to do (and also in terms of after the PhD).

My current advisor cannot advise me in this new field, since this is not his field. I talked to the dean of my department, and he said that in this case it makes sense to find a new advisor, and just move.
I am ok with starting over after two years, but I really feel bad leaving my advisor, after they spent so much time and effort in me. They funded me for the whole time, helped me navigate through the university bureaucracy, helped me to get scholarships (the last one is a pretty big one which I just received, and it made me feel so bad to accept it and leave. Needless to say, when I applied for it I did not know that leaving my advisor would be the option suggested by the dean).

I do not have one sharp question, but I need advice: how common is it? Should I offer to return the scholarships? How should I present it to my current advisor? (they don't know about me planning to leave, but it won't be a surprise for them at this point)

Comment: Where are you in the world? What sort of "scholarship"? - is it tied to a particular project?

Comment: Outside of the US, closer to Europe. Some of the scholarships were for academic excellence (and my advisor recommended on giving them to me), and some of them were from a lab focusing on the previous topic (but these scholarships do not tied to any specific project).

Comment: Are these funds for future work or those you've already received for your past work?

Comment: To be honest, I am not sure. My advisor sees it as a general reward for being a good student, and not as a reward for a specific project. The most recent scholarship might be given to me for future work.

Comment: How long  would it take to complete the current track? How close is the new subfield to the current one?

Comment: It will take two years to finish the current track. The new field is very far - I may even need to switch departments

Comment: Ok; the way things work in the US, where I am most familiar, is that as a grad student you are *paid* for some position, for doing some work. That work might be teaching, it might be research, or it might be from a fellowship. The latter is most like a "scholarship" in that it's funding the *student* rather than the research project, though there's often also a project attached (but there can be a lot of freedom in changing this). My understanding is most of Europe is somewhat similar at least in that PhD funding comes through holding some sort of "job"...

Comment: ...your scenario sounds more like you're getting handed bags of money at irregular intervals, which seems quite unusual to me. I suspect you'll need to be more specific about where exactly you are so you can get an answer from someone familiar with that context.

Comment: Just to make it clear - I did not get so much money. I got money for doing research and teaching, but in addition to that I received one award for excellence in research, and one scholarship from a fellowship. Both were thanks to the advisor's support (for one of them he could only choose one of his students to apply)

Comment: @gnometorule this is not the case. I have connections in the new field, as well as papers I wrote (which were submitted and are under review). So not a loose connection at all

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Switching advisors is common, but not extremely common. There are hundreds of reasons for it, but wanting to do a different topic is likely one of the rarer ones, especially if it results in lost time to completion. Even changing universities to find a better/more compatible advisor happens often enough. There are some bad advisors out there, but it isn't an extremely common occurrence.

If your time to completion is reasonably short, I'd suggest you just continue in the short term. You seem to have a really good advisor, which is a big plus and not guaranteed if you switch.

If the new track is somewhat similar to the current one, especially in research process, then you can certainly take it up in the future when you have a secure position. You aren't locked in to the topic of your dissertation through your whole career. The question is when is the best time to make a change. Usually that means early, if possible, but not if it delays your career. Think long term.

But for the case where the new field is very different, then staying where you are may just be wasting time. But think about the research process in the two fields. In mathematics and in history they are very different. In mathematics and CS they can be similar or quite different. The doctorate will give you skills in process, not just in topic.

But the bottom line advice is to consider your own needs and career, not the feelings of your current advisor. It is you that will live with the decision and most advisors will understand that you and they might have different goals.

Comment: Thanks. The main reason I want to move is that my current advisor is more applied, while I want to do more math/TCS. It means that in terms of getting skills - as you wrote - staying where I am right now would mean having a disadvantage. For example, when I write a proof, they cannot read it and give a valuable feedback (as they admit).

Comment: On the other hand, finding someone else who would read and comment on your proof is way easier than finding a good advisor. Maybe many of your issues can be solved by extending your collaboration network.

Comment: I tried that. But my current advisor demands to be a coauthor on any paper I will write while I was under his supervision, which is acceptable thing in his original community but not in the community I want to move to. New collaborators don't agree to that

Comment: Frankly speaking, new collaborators shouldn't ban people you add as co-authors, I find it odd. The advisor might be forced to show involvment in your matters (e.g., by being a co-author) if money spending is concerned, for example.

Comment: Depends on which community. In some communities, being a co author when you did nothing but paying is considered unethical.

Comment: Even in this case it is not my collaborator's job to oversee my ethical decisions, really. Then they should bring money instead. But it's quite an offtopic, sorry. I am just suspicious of people who want to have a bit too much of a control over my part.