# Can I switch disciplines in PhD programs?

Tags: publications, phd, computer-science, research-undergraduate

I am an undergraduate student, looking to apply to PhD programs in Computer Science next year.
I am interested in quite a lot of things in CS, especially Theoretical Computer Science and Artificial Intelligence/Machine Learning.
I am more leaning towards Theory and I think I will write that down in my SOP.
In case my interests change in grad school, will it be possible to change my area of focus to AI? Will that possible, considering that I am going to PhD programs straight after a BA?

Comment: Welcome to Academia.SE. "How do I switch fields?" is one of our most common questions -- please take a look in our archives and see what has already been answered; then you can create a new question to specify anything that remains unclear. If you do create a new one, please specify your location; this kind of thing will work differently in the US vs. Europe vs. elsewhere.

Comment: See also: [Switching PhD Topic](https://academia.stackexchange.com/questions/174042/switching-phd-topic-and-advisor) for a CS-specific example.